# Batch call Dependency id requirements?

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-ads-api

I have a script which does the following:

1. Create campaign
2. Create AdSet (requires campaign_id)
3. Create AdCreative (requires adset_id)
4. Create Ad (requires creative_id and adset_id)

I am trying to lump all of them into a batch request. However, I realized that my none of these gets created except for my campaign (step 1) if I use remote_create(batch=my_batch). This is probably due to the dependencies of the ids that are needed in by each of the subsequent steps.

I read the documentation and it mentions that one can "Specifying dependencies between operations in the request" (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/making-multiple-requests) between calls via {result=(parent operation name):(JSONPath expression)}

1. Is this possible with the python API?
2. Can this be achieved with the way I am using remote_creates?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately python sdk doesn't currently support this. There is a github issue for it: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-python-ads-sdk/issues/256.

I have also encountered this issue also and have described my workaround in the comments on the issue:

"I found a decent workaround for getting this behaviour without too much trouble. Basically I set the id fields that have dependencies with values like "{result=:$,id}" and prior to doing execute() on the batch object I iterate over ._batch and add as the 'name' entry. When I run execute sure enough it works perfectly. Obviously this solution does have it's limitations such where you are doing multiple calls to the same endpoint that need to be fed into other endpoints and you would have duplicated resource names and would need to customize the name further to string them together.
Anyways, hope this helps someone!"